# Unity 5 Camera Functions Usage Error

Tags: camera, unity

How to use functions like ScreenToRayPoint() in Camera class?

I have used this code:

`Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);`

and it says

> Component.camera is obsolete, instead using GetComponent()

Then I tried these:

`Camera cam = GetComponent<Camera>();`

`Ray ray = cam.ScreenToRayPoint(Input.mousePosition);`

and it says

> Camera doesn't contain a definition of ScreenPointToRay and no extension method 'ScreenPointToRay' accepting a first argument of type 'Camera' could be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work by the way. I think code you mentioned here is not exactly the same you used.

You did use `Camera.ScreenToRayPoint(Input.mousePosition);` instead of `cam.ScreenToRayPoint(Input.mousePosition);`

`cam.ScreenToRayPoint(Input.mousePosition);` should work without any doubt.

You can also use `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay` from anywhere. But be sure that your Main Camera has tagged with `"MainCamera"`

Comment: Do I need to import the namespace for Camera to work?

Comment: `Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);`
> Camera does not contain a definition for 'main'

Answer (score 0):

I have a script named Camera, that's why I get the error(overrode UnityEngine.Camera), thanks for all the helping!